# Small-o(n^2) implementation of Polynomial Multiplication

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, polynomial-math, convolution

I'm having a little trouble with this problem that is listed at the back of my book, i'm currently in the middle of test prep but i can't seem to locate anything regarding this in the book.

Anyone got an idea?

`A real polynomial of degree n is a function of the form f(x)=a(n)x^n+⋯+a1x+a0, where an,…,a1,a0 are real numbers. In computational situations, such a polynomial is represented by a sequence of its coefficients (a0,a1,…,an). Assuming that any two real numbers can be added/multiplied in O(1) time, design an o(n^2)-time algorithm to compute, given two real polynomials f(x) and g(x) both of degree n, the product h(x)=f(x)g(x). Your algorithm should **not** be based on the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) technique.`

Please note ***it needs to be small-o(n^2)***, which means its complexity must be sub-quadratic.

The obvious solution that i have been finding is indeed the FFT, but of course i can't use that. There is another method that i have found called convolution, where if you take polynomial A to be a signal and polynomial B to be a filter. A passed through B yields a shifted signal that has been "smoothed" by A and the resultant is A*B. This is supposed to work in O(n log n) time. Of course i am completely unsure of implementation.

If anyone has any ideas of how to achieve a small-o(n^2) implementation please do share, thanks.

Comment: man you are going through seriously complicated stuff... Take you pencil, two polynomials of small degree (2 for eg), and make the multiplication by hand. There you go, you have the `O(n^2)` algorithm, which is the trivial method.

Comment: it needs to be small-o, not big-o. Small-o is defined by complexity that doesn't quite reach n^2, but remains somewhere below it. Unless i'm completely misunderstanding it.

Comment: also multiplying two polynomials by hand gives us a run time that is actually Big-Theta(n^2) not O(n^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small-o : `f(x) = o(g(x)) is equivalent to lim x -> inf f(x)/g(x) = 0`.
Use the [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm)

Comment: thank you i had seen this before but i got lost in some unnecessary stuff